# Is it possible to use a cocoa control like inputtoolbar in Phonegap?

Tags: ios, cocoa, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have an app developed in jqueryMobile and Phonegap for iOS. I would like to use a cocoa control I have found called [InputToolbar](https://github.com/brandonhamilton/inputtoolbar/tree/master/UIInputToolbarSample)
Is it possible?